# C++ how to store Boolean data for fast bitwise AND operations [solved]

Tags: c++

I have a database with Boolean values with (at compile-time) unknown size.

For example:

```
    Dtb[100][6] = { {0,1,0,1,1,0},
                    {1,0,0,1,1,0},
                    {0,0,1,0,1,0},
                    ...          }
```

I will initialize it once (while running) and will not change it afterwards.

Then, I want to check for a item `i = {0,0,0,1,1,0}`, whether it appears in each row.

For example:

```
    for (row in Dtb) {
        // check
        i == i & row
    }
```

So if an entry in `i` is true, whether the corresponding entry is true in the `row`, as well.

I am interested in way to store my database in C++, so that these checks work very fast.

Yet, I considered to use `std:vector<std::vector<bool>>, std:vector<std::vector<char>>` (or not nested, saved columnwise), and I also came across `boost::dynamic_bitset`.
On my research I found so far that

- I should not use something like `std::vector<bool>`, because it is not a container
- `boost::dynamic_bitset` needs less storage than `std::vector<bool>`
- `std::vector<char>`is faster accessible, but it takes longer to initialize

As I could use the bitwise AND, I think, I do not need to access single bits, so `boost::dynamic_bitset` might be my best option?

**Edit:**

I must not use the `std::array` class, since I do not know the size of my database when compiling the code, as mentioned above.

The dimensions of the database can become big, so it should be possible to hold rows with about 100 values, as well.

**Solution:**

Considering this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220803585_Performance_of_C_bit-vector_implementations `boost::dynamic_bitset` seems to be the best choice when it comes to dynamically resizable bit-vector implementations for the C++.

However, I implemtented @Homer512 's `BoolMatrix class` and compared it to `boost::dynamic_bitset` and it appeared to be five times faster.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

#define ROWS 1000000
#define COLS 30
#define LOOPS 100

using namespace std;

// BoolMatrix class
class BoolMatrix {
private:
    std::size_t rows, bits_per_row, ints_per_row;
    std::vector<std::uint64_t> data;
public:
    BoolMatrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t bits_per_row)
        : rows(rows),
        bits_per_row(bits_per_row),
        ints_per_row((bits_per_row + 63) / 64),
        data(rows* ints_per_row) {
        for (std::uint64_t& ints : data) { ints = 0; }
    }

    void set(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) noexcept {
        data[row * ints_per_row + col / 64] |= ( 1 << (col % 64) );
    }

    int match_count(const std::uint64_t* subset) const noexcept {
        int count = 0;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (std::size_t j = 0; j < ints_per_row; ++j) {
                if ((data[i * ints_per_row + j] & subset[j]) != subset[j]) { break; } // mismatch
                if (j == ints_per_row - 1) { count++; } // match
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
};

// some auxiliary functions
void tic_clock(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start) {
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count() * 1e-9 << std::endl;
}
void set(bool* matrix, int row, int col, bool value) {
    matrix[row * COLS + col] = value;
}
bool get(bool* matrix, int row, int col) {
    return matrix[row * COLS + col];
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    bool* data;
    data = new bool[ROWS * COLS];
    assert(data != NULL);
    bool compare[COLS] = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 }; // 101000101010000000000111000101
    int counter;

    // generate random bool dtb
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            set(data, i, j, rand() % 2);
        }
    }
    tic_clock(start);

    //
    // vector of bitsets
    vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<uint32_t>> data_a(ROWS, boost::dynamic_bitset<uint32_t>(COLS));
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            // set data
            if (get(data,i,j)) { data_a[i].set(j); }
        }
    }
    tic_clock(start);
    
    boost::dynamic_bitset<uint32_t> compare_a(COLS);
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
        if (compare[j]) { compare_a.set(j); }
    }
    tic_clock(start);

    // count number of subsets !!!
    for (int k = 0; k < LOOPS; k++) {
        counter = 0;
        for (const auto& row : data_a) {
            if (compare_a.is_subset_of(row)) { counter++; }
        }
    }
    tic_clock(start);

    cout << counter << endl;
    
    //
    // BoolMatrix
    BoolMatrix data_b(ROWS, COLS);
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            // set data
            if (get(data, i, j)) { data_b.set(i,j); }
        }
    }
    tic_clock(start);

    std::uint64_t compare_b[(COLS + 63) / 64];
    compare_b[0] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
        if (compare[j]) { compare_b[j / 64] |= (1 << (j % 64)); } // stored reverse
    }
    tic_clock(start);

    // count number of subsets !!!
    for (int k = 0; k < LOOPS; k++) {
        counter = data_b.match_count(compare_b);
    }
    tic_clock(start);

    cout << counter << endl;

    delete[] data;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4.11788
5.92903
5.92976
10.8508 // -> takes ~5sec
870 // count
11.5189
11.5199
12.2765 // -> takes ~1sec
870 // count
```

Eventually there might be a gain in time, if I would use C for this, but I do not think that it would be much.

Thanks to @Homer512 for the fast and thorough answer.

Comment: `std::array<std::bitset<6>, 100>`?

Comment: It's probably faster to just save it as an unsigned integer, instead of a vector of chars or something.

Comment: *"but it takes longer to initialize"* -- is this a concern? Earlier you stated that your goal was to make the checks fast, with no indication that setup time is a concern. If it is a concern, then how do you rate the relative importance of setup speed and evaluation speed?

Comment: If it is **unknown size** at compile time, I'd use the standard container `std::vector<bool>`.  (That standard container is optimized for smallest footprint.)

Comment: @JaMiT the time for initialization does not matter. I just think that there must be a faster method to check this than comparing vector<char> entries.

Comment: You could have a look at AVX intstructions and datatypes (you can then process a lot of bits per clock cycle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boost::dynamic_bitset<T>` is just a fancy wrapper around `std::vector<T>`. Therefore performance comparisons between the two come down to how good you are at implementing your operation on vectors compared to the boost developers.

Unless you want to get your hands really dirty with micro-optimizing your comparison, `dynamic_bitset` is probably the better choice as it comes with handy functions such as `is_subset` which implement exactly what you seem to want.

### Picking the integer type

The integer type `T` for the bitset can be chosen freely. Pick the largest reasonable type. Usually `uint64_t` or `size_t` unless you know you have fewer bits. The reasons are simple:

1. Your comparison function is limited by instruction throughput. A larger type allows checking more bits per instruction. Therefore picking something small like unsigned char would limit you severely (or put you at the mercy of your compilers vectorizer which I wouldn't count on here)
2. Compared to the overhead of the dynamic allocation and the bitset datatype itself, wasting a few bytes by picking a larger payload type is insignificant

### `vector<bool>`

Internally, `vector<bool>` uses the same layout. There is nothing to be gained here. Its interface makes large set-like comparisons like the one you want slower than they need to be.

### boolean matrix

Two observations:

1. A few 100 bit isn't really a large number. That's only a couple 64 bit integers. Using a dynamic allocation for that is pretty wasteful and kills the locality of data
2. From your example it seems like all rows are equally sized

In this case, you could consider a densely packed boolean matrix type instead. Writing one is simple enough. The improved prefetching alone may already make it worthwhile. Something like this:

```
struct BoolMatrix
{
  std::size_t rows, bits_per_row, ints_per_row;
  std::vector<std::uint64_t> data;

  BoolMatrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t bits_per_row)
  : rows(rows),
    bits_per_row(bits_per_row),
    ints_per_row((bits_per_row + 63) / 64),
    data(rows * ints_per_row)
  {}
  void set(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) noexcept
  {
    data[row * ints_per_row + col / 64] |=
          std::uint64_t(1) << (col % 64);
  }
  std::size_t first_match(const std::uint64_t* subset) const noexcept
  {
    std::size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
      std::size_t j;
      for(j = 0; j < ints_per_row; ++j)
        if((data[i * ints_per_row + j] & subset[j]) != subset[j])
          break; // mismatch
      if(j == ints_per_row)
        return i;
    }
    return i; // no match. return N
  }
};
```